# Masking BGR image using a 2D mask

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, mask

I have a three-dimensional array (image) with shape `(480, 640, 3)`. Here, the 3 refers to `BGR` color code. I would like to place a mask over this image using the data from the array of the Red image. Depending on its value, certain pixels need to be masked.

Creating the mask works fine. It behaves exactly as expected. In order to apply the mask to the original image, I first apply the mask to the Blue and Green image. All is still fine. Now I stack the three masked arrays, which returns an array with shape `(480, 640, 3)`. However, plotting this array using `imshow` results in the original image. No sign of any mask.

Below I put my code. The code works for any image size/shape. All you need to do is change the name `"Whatever_image_you_like.png"` to the name of any image on your pc.

```
import numpy
import numpy.ma
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pixel_value = 130   #Value in range 0 to 255

image = scipy.misc.imread("Whatever_image_you_like.png")

#Extract Blue, Green, and Red image from original image
image_B = numpy.copy(image[:, :, 0])
image_G = numpy.copy(image[:, :, 1])
image_R = numpy.copy(image[:, :, 2])

#Define mask depending on pixel value in Red image
image_mask = numpy.empty([image.shape[0], image.shape[1]], dtype = bool)
image_mask[image_R < pixel_value] = False

#Apply mask to Blue, Green, and Red images
B_masked = numpy.ma.masked_array(image_B, mask = ~image_mask)
G_masked = numpy.ma.masked_array(image_G, mask = ~image_mask)
R_masked = numpy.ma.masked_array(image_R, mask = ~image_mask)

#Stack masked images together again
masked_image = numpy.ma.dstack((B_masked, G_masked, R_masked))

#Plot original image and masked version
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax1.imshow(image)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax2.imshow(masked_image)

plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: It looks like `imshow`, does not use the mask for masked arrays with RGB values. A quick hack can be to use RGBA values: `masked_image2 = numpy.dstack([image, (~image_mask).astype(numpy.uint8)*255])`

Comment: Looks to me like you create your mask in a strange way. You set it to empty (which makes the elements take an unknown value) and then set a subset of them to False. Are you sure you dont just want `image_mask = image_R < pixel_value`?

Comment: @Jan Kuiken this is an hack. This is the proper answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use a mask with the same shape as the `image` (actually, this will be a 3D mask). After generating your `image_mask`, do

```
# create mask with same dimensions as image
mask = numpy.zeros_like(image)

# copy your image_mask to all dimensions (i.e. colors) of your image
for i in range(3): 
    mask[:,:,i] = image_mask.copy()

# apply the mask to your image
masked_image = image[mask]
```

This way I avoid masked arrays in numpy for the time being.

Comment: If the answer suits your needs, please mark it as solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this alternative approach would be easier in similar cases:

```
image[image_mask,:] = np.nan
```