# Masking BGR image using a 2D mask error in displaying

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to mask a colored image with a 2D mask in python. I have tried the solution given in the answer here [Masking BGR image using a 2D mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821137/masking-bgr-image-using-a-2d-mask) but it is not displaying the desired result.

I have tried this code from a previous answer:

```
mask = np.zeros_like(image)

# copy your image_mask to all dimensions (i.e. colors) of your image
for i in range(3):
    mask[:,:,i] = image_mask.copy()

masked_image = image[mask]
```

where the image has the shape (522, 775, 3) and the image_mask has the shape (522, 775) and 0 or 1 as values.

```
masked_image.shape
```

is outputting this (522, 775, 3, 775, 3) and therefore the image is not displayed.

The expected result would be the masked image with 0s in places where the mask is 0 as well. Instead, I get a strange shape in the resulting masked_image and cannot understand why. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Note that the answer to the linked question is given in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821137/masking-bgr-image-using-a-2d-mask#comment42250759_26821137) below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you multiply your image with the mask?

```py
mask = np.zeros_like(image)

# copy your image_mask to all dimensions (i.e. colors) of your image
for i in range(3):
    mask[:,:,i] = image_mask.copy()

masked_image = image * mask
```