# Vectorized way to apply a 3-dimension mask to RGB in pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, mask

I have a HxWx3 tensor representing an RGB image and a HxWx3 mask (boolean) tensor as input.
It is assumed that for each (i,j) in the mask tensor there's exactly one true value (that is exactly one of R\G\B is on).
I want to apply the mask to the image to result in a HxW (or HxWx1) tensor V where V[i,j]='the matching R\G\B value according to the mask'.

Using [Problem applying binary mask to an RGB image with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453114/problem-applying-binary-mask-to-an-rgb-image-with-numpy) I was able to achieve the following:

```
>>> X*mask
tensor([[[ 9., 10.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0., 20.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [30.,  0.]]])
```

But as stated, I want a single dim HxW and not HxWx3 as result.

Illustration:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that for each i,j only a single R/G/B value is retained, you can simply do:

```
(X*mask).sum(axis=2)
```

This should give you your desired (HxW) output.

Comment: If it works with axis 0 then your tensors must have been CxHxW rather than HxWxC.